# Specific directory permission for one user using sftp

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, webserver, sftp

My web server structure looks like this:

```
/Home/User/Public_Html/Website_one
                      /Website_two
                      /Website_three/Directory_one
                                    /Directory_two
                                    /Directory_three 
                                    /Directory_four
```

Now, I need my friend to have access from this server only to `Directory_two` and `Directory_four` under `website_three`.

I have created an SFTP account based on [SFTP Jails](http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails). I also created a `home` folder for him and SFTP works fine. But the problem is I couldn't give him access to those directories with sub files. How can I give him access only to `Directory_two` and `Directory_four`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use either `mount --bind` or `bindfs` to re-mount those directories (possibly read-only or with special permissions or ownership depending on what you want to do exactly) inside the SFTP `chroot` jail your friend has access to.